# Adding team members on Onsen IDE

Tags: onsen-ui, monaca

I upgraded to the developer level on the Onsen IDE. It seems that at that level it is still not possible to add a team member. At what level is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

As described on [Monaca's pricing page](https://monaca.mobi/en/pricing), it's possible to access Team features with the Gold plan.